# How to Run a Java Class File from the Command Line that was Compiled by Eclipse? External Jar problems

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have a project that runs fine in Eclipse. The project uses many external jars.
My file directory for the project has a `bin` and `src` directory, and a `.classpath` and `.project` files.

From this directory, if I execute:

```
java -cp bin com.brm.main.Demo2
```

I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/sea
rch/Query
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.Query
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

org/apache/lucene is an external jar.

Comment: Your classpath is invalid and so the .jars for external libraries aren't found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to include your other dependencies on the classpath, separating classpath elements with `;` on Windows or `:` on Linux.

On Windows:

```
java -cp bin;path\to\lucene.jar com.brm.main.Demo2
```

On Linux:

```
java -cp bin:path/to/lucene.jar com.brm.main.Demo2
```

If you have other jarfiles or directories in addition to lucene and bin, you'll have to add those, too.

If you're trying to deploy your program, a better solution is to use Eclipse's "Export" wizard to export a Runnable JAR File, which will walk you through the steps to select your main class and bundle your dependencies.  Or, going even further, you can use ant or maven to build your project and create a deployable bundle.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying like this:-

```
java -cp .;%CLASSPATH% com.brm.main.Demo2
```

seems like your classpath is invalid and because of that the .jars for the external libraries are not found.

Comment: When I execute this in the same directory, I receive the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class Files`. even if I include the bin in the class path?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen:- Could you try with simple java -cp .  by using the specify the fully qualified class name

Comment: @MatthewMoisen:- Or better try like this: java -cp bin;path\to\lucene.jar com.brm.main.Demo2